# Overriding udchcp flags used by ifup in BusyBox

Tags: busybox, udhcpc

I am working on a system that I did not create the BusyBox build for. I do not want to recompile BusyBox for fear that my configuration will not completely match the original and besides this the system is functioning well enough on this build. I could be swayed to do this if I knew of a way to pull the configuration of a running BusyBox install much like a running kernel.

I am trying to figure out how to disable the switches used to call `udhcpc` from the `ifup` command. I can see the defaults compiled into the build that I am using. They are `-R -n -p`. I want for this process to fork into the background and I thought using `udhcpc_opts -b` in `/etc/networking/interfaces` would solve this issue. I get the fork to the background and then the process kills. If i just call `udhcpc -b` it forks to the background indefinitely.

Is there a way to override the `-n` switch through something I can put into `udhcpc_opts`? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having the same problem, did not want to recompile busybox and wanted to use those flags: "-t 0 -b" to let udhcpc try forever in background, but could not avoid flag "-n" that is passed by default by ifup.

As a super-hack (but it worked for me) I used the following options for udhcpc_opts in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
udhcpc_opts -t 0 -T 10 -A 20 -S &
```

The final "&" did the trick, as it launchs udhcpc as a background task and is almost the same of the "-b" flag, but works also if the "-n" is specified in the command line.

Note, that it has to be added to `iface` option to work, eg:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    udhcpc_opts -t 0 -T 10 -A 20 -S &
```

Comment: selected this as the answer because it would avoid the recompile I ultimately did

Answer (score 3):

Behavior of `udhcpc -n -b` has been corrected to behave like `udhcpc -b` in a [fix](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=87e216294af9eec39c0c1d553555f8a98c15db38) for [busybox bug #11691](https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=11691).

Thus, starting with busybox-1.31 (yet to be released as of now), `udhcpc_opts -b` should just work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was unable to override the default switches. I was able to append switches to the default call of udhcpc, but the switch forking to the background, `-b`, and exiting on failure, `-n`, are not mutually exclusive. Thus forking to the background would not stop the exiting behavior.

To append the switches to the command, I had to add `udhcpc_opts` to the in the ethX stanze of the /etc/network/interfaces file.

Ultimately I wound up having to recompile busybox so that the udhcpc process could fork to the background and remain running.